# Find intersection point coordinates OpenCV Python

Tags: python-2.7, intersection, opencv3.0, hough-transform

I have to find corner points of fallowing image. I am using OpenCV 3.1.0 in Python 2.7

[image: Conner points are marked in blue dot]

I have used Houghline detection. But, Its find outer lines of the papers.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    frame=cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(3,3),0);  
    cv2.adaptiveThreshold(frame,255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, 
CV_THRESH_BINARY,75,10);  

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
    cv2.imshow('canny',edges)
    lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,r,t,th)
    for rho,theta in lines[0]:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

        cv2.line(frame,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)
    #Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(40) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Suggest a suitable way to get intersection point coordinates. If you can give some example code.

Comment: Is your Hough line detection working correctly ? Do you get all the lines in the image ? Can you show an output example ?

Comment: No..I got only one line. If i move the paper, It was changed.